# Calling generic Java function with <?> parameter

Tags: java, generics, casting, unchecked

Is the following possible somehow?

```
interface Foo<T> {
    public void bar(T object);
}
```

...

```
public void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
    foo.bar("Hello world!");
}
```

Clearly, this is not type-safe as it is assuming that `Foo<?>` in this case actually is a `Foo<String>`.

But rather than the usual "unchecked" warning, this actually gives me the following error: *The method bar(capture#1-of ?) in the type Foo is not applicable for the arguments (String)*

Usually there's some casting I can do to turn this exception into the warning I want, but somehow I can't find one right now...

Any thoughts (**other than "don't do this!", please**)?

**EDIT:**

It seems like everyone **does** want to discuss the "don't do this", so let me explain the entire problem I'm trying to solve as elegantly as possible and then maybe someone has a cleaner way to do this...

I'm trying to write a flexible eventbus system, where I don't need to declare a billion interface types for each event.

I want to have a class `EventBus` that looks like this:

```
public class EventBus<GroupType, EventType>  {

  ...

  public void addHandler(EventHandler<GroupType, EventType, ?> handler, GroupType group, EventType... events) {
    //                                                      ^ this is the <?> !!!
    // add handler to list of handlers for group and requested event types
  }


  public <Source> void fireEvent(GroupType group, EventType event, Source source) {
    // call all handlers registered for group and event type
  }
}
```

where the interface `EventHandler` looks like this:

```
public interface EventHandler<GroupType, EventType, Source> {
  public void onEvent(GroupType group, EventType event, Source source);
}
```

That way, I can simply write my event handlers to look like this:

```
public class Handler implements EventHandler<Groups, Events, TextBox> {
  public void onEvent(Groups group, Events event, TextBox source) {
    // Do something with source immediately
  }
}
```

where `Groups` and `Events` are Enums that describe the possible event types.

Then I register them with

```
addHandler(myHandler, Groups.EDIT_BOXES, Events.VALUE_CHANGED, Events.CLEARED, ...);
```

And I can call them with

```
fireEvent(Groups.EDIT_BOXES, Events.VALUE_CHANGED, myEditField);
```

In my code, I **know** that in the group `EDIT_BOXES` all sources are of type `TextBox` and I don't want to type-cast my life away in every handler I write. That's why I would like to be able to implement the specific interface in the handler, but call it with an unsafe typecast from the EventBus (which I write once and hide forever) rather than having to write all my handlers like this:

```
public class Handler implements EventHandler<Groups, Events> {
  public void onEvent(Groups group, Events event, Object source) {
    TextBox usableSource = (TextBox) source;
    // Do something with usableSource
  }
}
```

And if the cast is wrong, the program will and should crash and burn either way. Even if I put an "instanceof" check in the handler, I will need to somehow throw that as an error. I can do that elegantly, but it doesn't really matter, since any error in this scenario is a bug in the code that needs to be fixed and not some runtime user-error, which I should gracefully inform the user of.

Now, I've seen other libraries implement a completely type-safe event system, but often this involves having to declare interfaces for every possible type of event and every possible type of event handler and sometimes even for functions on the eventbus itself, which, if you ask me, is WAY more pain than it's worth.

If any of you have a clean way to do what I'm trying to achieve, I'd be stoked. But I'm not sure it's doable any other way.

Comment: did u try it like this: `public void callBar(Foo<String> foo) {
    foo.bar("Hello world!");
}`

Comment: Clearly that would be the "correct" way to do it, but I don't only want to call foo.bar with Strings but potentially also with Integers, etc. in this method...

Comment: I guess I could specify the SourceType along with the GroupType and EventType in the definition of the EventBus and then have a different EventBus for each of my source types, but since I wanted to add some logging and monitoring capability to the EventBus, I wanted to have a "one-stop-shop" where all events pass through.

Comment: Have you looked at Guava's [`EventBus`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained)?  It has an interesting approach to maintaining type safety.

Comment: @LouisWasserman That looks really interesting, but quite involved behind the scenes. Since I'm working on this for a GWT app, I'm not sure how much of it I can use (no reflection, etc.), but I will definitely see if I can borrow some idea from there. The annotation method of adding handlers is a very nice touch. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... Just figured it out:

```
public void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
    ((Foo<String>) foo).bar("Hello world!");
}
```

Comment: This looks very dangerous to me as it removes exactly what generics are supposed to help with -- compile time type safety.

Comment: Accept it, for future users.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am fully aware of this, but it makes some of my other code infinitely nicer. (I am working on an event bus system, where I don't want to have to define a billion helper classes for each type of event... GWT, for example, needs THREE!!! classes (Has...Handlers, ...Event, and ...Handler) for each event type. It's nuts!)

Answer (score 4):

You propose that this is a solution:

```
public void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
    ((Foo<String>) foo).bar("Hello world!");
}
```

I claim that if this *does* work that there is something wrong with your API's typing.

One possibility is that all the places where `callBar` is going to be called, the `foo` will actually be a `Foo<String>`.  But if that is the case, then the (generic) method signature is incorrect.  You should declare it as:

```
public void callBar(Foo<String> foo) {
    foo.bar("Hello world!");
}
```

Another possibility is that the `bar` method will actually work just fine when called with an argument that doesn't match the generic type; e.g.

```
Foo<Integer> f = ...
f.bar("Hello world!");
```

doesn't cause any runtime breakages due to `"Hello world!"` having the wrong time.  In that case you have probably declared the method signature in the interface incorrectly.  It should be:

```
public void bar(Object object);
```

A third possibility is that your code works for a particular implementation of the `Foo.bar` method, and that you are only going to use it with those implementations.  But if that is the case, your code should reflect this:

```
public void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
    if (foo instanceof SomeFooImpl) {
        foo.realBar("Hello world!");
    } else {
        throw InvalidArgument("barring the wrong kind of foo");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class SomeFooImpl<T> implements Foo<T> {
    ...
    public void bar(T object) {
        realBar(object);
    }

    publiC void realBar(Object object) {
        System.out.print("Breaker breaker - come in '" + object + "'"));
    }
}
```

(Note we can't overload `bar` and `realBar`; i.e. give them the same name.  The methods need to have different erased signatures ...)

---

But the bottom line is that what you are proposing as the correct solution is *liable* to result in the `foo` method being called with an actual argument that doesn't match the base type.  That is WRONG, at least from perspective of the type signatures as you have declared them.

---

**UPDATE** in response to your comment.

I think that the best solution is to change this:

```
public interface EventHandler<GroupType, EventType, Source> {
    public void onEvent(GroupType group, EventType event, Source source);
}
```

to

```
public interface EventHandler<GroupType, EventType> {
    public void onEvent(GroupType group, EventType event, Object source);
}
```

This means that a specific handler will need to type-cast the `source` object to the type that it is expecting.  But this is pretty much mandated your EventBus API ... which seems to be saying that the handler registration and dispatching is agnostic of the source type of the handler objects.  It is probably good from a functional perspective too, because it allows a single handler to handle events from multiple source types.

(Comment: your API design looks like you might be focussing too much on elegant use of generics ... at the expense of supporting the functionality that an event bus needs to provide.  My conception of an event bus is that it should avoid static dependencies between the suppliers and consumers of events.  This means that it needs to be able to dynamically "deal with" type mismatches between the the producers and consumers.  But your use of generics seems to be (re-)introducing static type dependencies ... )

Comment: Hi Stephen, please see the edits to my original post... Maybe you have a way to do what I'm trying to do in a clean way.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a generic interface, don't make the method call it with a specific type. Or don't use a specific type and stay generic

```
interface Foo<T> {
    public void bar(T object);
}

class SomeGenericClass {
    public <T> void callGenericBar(Foo<T> foo, T param) {
        foo.bar(param);
    }
    public void callStringBar(Foo<String> foo) {
        foo.bar("Hello");
    }
}
```

If you do it like

```
public void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
    ((Foo<String>) foo).bar("Hello world!");
}
```

The following code will compile fine:

```
interface Foo<T> {
    public void bar(T object);
}

class StringFoo implements Foo<String> {
    public void bar(String object) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}

class IntFoo implements Foo<Integer> {
    public void bar(Integer object) {
        System.out.println(object);
    }
}

class TestClass {
    public static void callBar(Foo<?> foo) {
        ((Foo<String>) foo).bar("Hello world!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringFoo foo1 = new StringFoo();
        IntFoo foo2 = new IntFoo();
        callBar(foo1);
        callBar(foo2);
    }
}
```

But: once you run it you get

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

It *requires* that `foo` is a `Foo<String>`. Use

```
public static void callBar(Foo<String> foo) {
    foo.bar("Hello world!");
}
```

And if you have multiple types of Foo use method overloading.

Comment: I edited my original post to describe what I'm trying to do. Maybe then it'll be clearer why I am asking the question, and maybe you have an idea of how to solve my actual problem.

Comment: @Markus For example like Stephen C said make it an `Object` instead of a generic. `interface  EventHandler<GroupType, EventType> { public void onEvent(GroupType group, EventType event, Object source); }` Or even better use a specialized class instead of `Object` that knows how to do type specific part you do in `TextBox usableSource = (TextBox) source`

Comment: Right... but then I'd have to type-cast in EVERY handler function and would still run into errors if that type cast doesn't succeed. So, all I'm doing is adding tons of more code to move the location of where the exception is thrown for a severe bug in my code from the eventbus to the handler. Although that may actually be useful for debugging, I am going to try very hard to avoid this error in the first place anyways, and would therefore rather not reduce the readability of my handlers for it.

Comment: @Markus Then make `Source` an interface that abstracts the type casting away and use `Source` as a class instead of a generic. E.g. a `TextBoxSource`

Comment: Hmm... sounds like an interesting idea, but I'm not sure I understand it fully. Would all my sources then need to implement Source and provide functions like TextBox asTextBox() ? In some cases, unfortunately, that won't be possible, like for example if I want to use TextBox (or some other externally provided final object) as my event source without having to wrap it.